# XSLT Reverse template order via apply-templates or call-template?

Tags: xml, xslt, reverse

I am writing a transform for a set of nodes, similar to this.

```
  <xsl:template match="/" name="nav">
        <!--do stuff-->
      <xsl:if test="notEnd">
       <xsl:call-template name="nav"></xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

The result it generates is top down (recursive):

```
<!--do stuff 5-->
<!--do stuff 4-->
<!--do stuff 3-->
<!--do stuff 2-->
<!--do stuff 1-->
```

The problem is after it generates the result, I need it to be in the correct order:

```
<!--do stuff 1-->
<!--do stuff 2-->
<!--do stuff 3-->
<!--do stuff 4-->
<!--do stuff 5-->
```

I am out of ideas on how to resort this after recursion? Should I use another template and implement apply-templates or is there a another way I can reverse the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you add the recursive call before the do stuff?

```
  <xsl:template match="/" name="nav">
      <xsl:if test="notEnd">
       <xsl:call-template name="nav"></xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
      <!--do stuff-->
  </xsl:template>
```

You should get the reverse order.

Comment: Thank you, :) it seems that did the trick, would have never thought about trying that, it makes sense without making sense :D

Answer (score 0):

To understand recursion, first you must understand recursion.

Comment: To iterate is fine, to recurse is divine.